# View checstyle XML results from Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, checkstyle

I have a pipeline in Azure DevOps that generated checkstyle report as an artifact in XML format. I'm looking for ways how to show the results of the checkstyle run like we are showing test results on the Tests tab. Test results artifacts can be used to generate an Allure report, so I'm looking for a tool/solution like 'allure' but for checkstyle XML results. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put is as summary as it shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#uploadsummary-add-some-markdown-content-to-the-build-summary)

```yaml
##vso[task.uploadsummary]c:\testsummary.md
```

However you need to prepate that repost as markdown file.